# How to find the formula of a binary compound if we know the mass of solid product and the volume of escaped gas?

Tags: stoichiometry

> During the decomposition of a binary compound two simple substances
> were formed: 44.8 grams of metal and 47.04 liters of a non-flammable
> gas (conditions are normal). Find chemical formula of the reagent.

Dear community, of course I tried to solve it myself, so I think I did put some effort. Firstly, I calculated the quantity of substance of the escaped gas:

ν(gas) = V(gas) : Vm(gases) = 47.04 l : 22.4 l/mol = **2.1 mol.**

I have a strong hypothesis that the escaped gas must have diatomic molecules. We know noble gases have monoatomic molecules, but they can hardly be products of any reaction.

So I tried writing my equation as: **kMₐXb -----> akM + (bk/2)X₂↑**

(Sorry, I have no ideas about how to write a subscript letter b.)

After this step, it became more like a game of guessing. I tried to divide the number 44.8 by different quotients of 2.1 over multiple natural numbers:

44.8 : 2.1 = 21.333 — apparently no such element in sign;

44.8 : (2.1 : 2) = 42.666;

44.8 : (2.1 : 3) = 64 — here is at least something good, 64 is copper. However, copper cannot have a valence of six.

44.8 : (2.1 : 4) = 85.333 — rubidium?

I am not sure at all if I must continue. May rubidium be the correct M? No clear ideas how to find  X though.

What am I missing and how to solve my problem? Help really needed.